# The product of metrizable space and one point lindelofication of the discrete space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be the [one point lindefication of a discret space of cardinality $\omega_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309698/one-point-lindelofication-of-a-discrete-space-of-cardinality-omega-1) and $Y$ is any metrizable space. Is $X \times Y$ always Lindelöf?

If I may ask more, does a metric space $Y$ with $e(Y)=\omega$ which is not lindelöf exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Just start with a metric space $Y$ that isn’t Lindelöf: then $\{0\}\times Y$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$ that isn’t Lindelöf, so $X\times Y$ can’t be Lindelöf, either.

Comment: If I may ask more,  does a metric space $Y$ with $e(Y)=\omega$ which is not lindelof exist?

Comment: @Paul: No: every metrizable space is a $D$-space, and if $X$ is a $D$-space, $e(X)=L(X)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are always kindful. (If I could ask more: If $Y$ is Lindelof, then is $X\times Y$ always lindelof?)

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome. Hmm... Let $p$ be the point at infinity in $X$, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X\times Y$. Some countable $\mathscr{U}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ covers $\{p\}\times Y$. Since $\mathscr{U}_0$ is countable, it’s not hard to show that that there is an $\alpha\in\omega_1$ such that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0\supseteq(\alpha,\omega_1]\times Y$, and $[0,\alpha]\times Y$ is certainly Lindelöf, so yes, $X\times Y$ is Lindelöf in this case.

Comment: Thanks! You are very smart!

Comment: @Paul: Thanks! It helps that I’ve been doing this stuff for a long time now.

Comment: What's time in your lacation now? I hope I could meet you in the right time.

Comment: @Paul: It’s about 07:50 here now; I’m in [UTC -0500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9205:00).